# Access to Deep data via Firebase Admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

How Can I Access to Deep data via Firebase Admin?

**Data:**

```
{
    "keyboards": {
        "StartKeyboard": [
            "KeyboardA",
            "KeyboardB",
            "KeyboardC"
        ],
        "SecendKeyboard": {
            "parent": "StartKeyboard",
            "childs": [      //*** I need to get this childs: [] ***
                "Keyboard1",
                "Keyboard2",
                "Keyboard3"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**When I use below Code, I have all data in output**

```
const ref = db.ref('/');    All Data
ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
```

**When I use below Code, I have childs of `keyboards` in output**

```
 const ref = db.ref('keyboards');   // inside of Keyboards
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });
```

But I Don't Know How to get `childs` of `SecendKeyboard`/`childs`.
I mean array of  `Keyboard1` and `Keyboard2` and `Keyboard3` .
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the keyboard children:

```
const ref = db.ref('keyboards/SecendKeyboard/childs');
ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Or:

```
const ref = db.ref('keyboards/SecendKeyboard');
ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.child("childs").val());
});
```

Or

```
const ref = db.ref('keyboards');
ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val()); // prints StartKeyboard and SecendKeyboard
        if (snapshot.child("SecendKeyboard").exists()) {
            console.log(snapshot.child("SecendKeyboard").val());
        }
    })
});
```